# Why has the syntax changed from flask.ext.* to flask_*?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

It looks like there was a deprecation.  How was that decided?  Is there a difference between Python 3 and Python 2?

Comment: What exactly do you think has changed?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'd just like to know a little about what's under the hood.  May I ask why this question was downvoted?

Answer (score 5):

The old `flask.ext` [was deprecated in issue #1135](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1135), which was created back in 2014.  The actual deprecation notice was turned on in 2016. The [reasoning behind the deprecation is](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1135#issuecomment-61860862):

> Some introductory information for new contributors:
>
> Flask used to have flaskext as a namespace for extensions, so they were importable as flaskext.foo. This didn't work well, so the new form flask_foo was introduced. flask.ext.foo is a compatibility layer that will try to import both variants. See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/extensions/
>
> flask.ext.foo is hard to maintain, and since now all extensions have switched to the new package naming scheme, it is no longer worth it. We want to deprecate it for 1.0, so we need some sort of tool which can help users to rewrite all their old imports in their apps.
>
> One could write a Python script similar to this beast. This will get the job done, but as its docstring says, it's a terrible hack.
>
> lib2to3 proved useful for writing larger migration tools, but it's nontrivial to use it.
>
> - https://github.com/mitsuhiko/python-modernize/ is one based on it, and it seems to me that's the easiest project one could rip off from.
> - I wasn't able to find complete tutorials that are useful for this. Most seem to be focused on porting to Python 3, which would imply running the default 2to3 fixers on the user's codebase (which we definetly don't want)
> - One will have to read the sourcecode of 2to3 and lib2to3 to understand, i think. This is doable by entering libraryname hg.python.org into Google, where the libraryname is either 2to3 or lib2to3.
> - The current state for doing sourcecode manipulation in Python sucks, and i'd like to see a library which wraps lib2to3 and provides a more concise API.

The old .ext was a compatibility layer to support the old `flaskext` module while waiting for `flask_` to standardize.

This separates the `flask.` namespace from each module's namespace, as the module now lives completely in its own module (`flask_module`) instead of being loaded into a general namespace for all extensions in Flask. It's also clearer that the module is not bundled as a part of Flask.